# Cannot import from package in same namespace tree until pkg_resources has been imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, pkg-resources

I have a strange problem that I somehow cannot reproduce separately, yet it shows up in production code, and of course the production code cannot be shared publically.

I have two packages, for argument's sake `ns.server` and `ns.protobuf`, where the latter implements protobuf specific extensions for the project. Both packages properly declare the namespace packages in setup.py, and both have the boilerplate pkg_resources stuff in `__init__.py`:

```
try:
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
    from pkgutil import extend_path
    __path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

Now for some strange reason, I get this:

```
>>> import ns.protobuf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named protobuf
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> import ns.protobuf
>>>
```

So it appears that my namespaces are all screwy until I import pkg_resources and then it is fixed. It's not too bad, the workaround is then simply to import pkg_resources first. I would just like to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh, second question I self-answer in as many days. I had a stale egg-info directory lying around in `lib/python2.7/site-packages`, from a previous install where I accidentally neglected to pass -e (development mode) to pip. Completely clearing everything and reinstalling fixed it.